# JQuery Append cloned select list in another SELECT if the list is not already append

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page, i have two select list with elements et one select list where i ll append the list selected.

My first select contain some elements, and it s called **REGIONS**

```
<select name="REGIONS" id="REGIONS" size="7" class="form-control" multiple="">
            <option value="01">01 - GUADELOUPE</option>
            <option value="02">02 - MARTINIQUE</option>
            <option value="03">03 - GUYANE</option><option value="04">04 - LA REUNION</option>
</select>
```

This second select , with id "**LIST_DEP**", is dynamic that means it depends by the item that has selected in the #REGIONS (there are showed the départements of the region selected) .

```
 <select name="LISTE_DEP" id="LISTE_DEP" onchange="" size="5" class="form-control" multiple=""><option value="91">91 - ESSONNE</option>
<option value="92">92 - HAUTS-DE-SEINE</option>
<option value="75">75 - PARIS</option>
<option value="77">77 - SEINE-ET-MARNE</option>
<option value="93">93 - SEINE-SAINT-DENIS</option>
<option value="94">94 - VAL-DE-MARNE</option>
<option value="95">95 - VAL-D'OISE</option><option value="78">78 - YVELINES</option>
</select>
```

At least, i have a third select called **GEO_SELECTED** (at begin it s empty) where i will append, with a double ckick on the region in the first list **REGIONS**, the list showed in **LIST_DEP** .

All it work fine ! but i would like check if in **GEO_SELECTED**, there is already the selected list beacause if i click for two time, or more, on the same REGIONS, that will be append every time that i do double click.

That's my function:

```
function addRegions()
{
    var regions =$("#LISTE_DEP > option").clone();
    
    for(i = 0; i < regions.length;i++){
    
        //if ($("#GEO_SELECTED").has(regions[i]).length == 0) in this condition i would like check if the list is already append
            $("#GEO_SELECTED").append(regions[i]);      
            
    }
}
```

How can i check if the list is already append? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Make the button a one off button using `one` instead of `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the following can point you in the right direction.

Here's a recording of the below code in action:

[image]

```js
( function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    
    // Get all our select fields,
    const $regions = $( 'select[name="regions"]' );
    const $departments = $( 'select[name="departments"]' );
    const $selected = $( 'select[name="selected"]' );
    
    // Listen for click on one of our action buttons.
    $( document ).on( 'click', '[data-list-action]', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $button = $( this );
        
        switch( $button.data( 'list-action' ) ) {
            case 'add':
                
                // Get the current values (array of option values).
                const regionsValue = $regions.val();
                const departmentsValue = $departments.val();
            
                // Get releated option DOM elements from array values.
                const $selectedRegions = $regions.find( 'option' ).filter( function() {
                    return regionsValue.includes( $( this ).attr( 'value' ) );
                } );
                
                const $selectedDepartments = $departments.find( 'option' ).filter( function() {
                    return departmentsValue.includes( $( this ).attr( 'value' ) );
                } );
                
                // Add their relative types (use when being removed from the selected field).
                $selectedRegions.data( 'type', 'regions' );
                $selectedDepartments.data( 'type', 'departments' );
            
                // Add to selected list.
                $selected.append( $selectedRegions );
                $selected.append( $selectedDepartments );
                break;
                
            case 'remove':
            
                // Get all the selected values we want to remove.
                const selectedValue = $selected.val();
                const $selectedOptions = $selected.find( 'option' ).filter( function() {
                    return selectedValue.includes( $( this ).attr( 'value' ) );
                } );
                
                
                // Move selected values back into their original select fields.
                $selectedOptions.each( function() {
                    const $option = $( this );
                    const type = $option.data( 'type' );
                    
                    $( `select[name="${type}"]` ).append( $option );
                } );
                
                break;
        }
        
        // Sort options.
        const $orderedRegions = $regions.find( 'option' ).sort( ( a, b ) => $( b ).text() < $( a ).text() ? 1 : -1 );
        const $orderedDepartments = $departments.find( 'option' ).sort( ( a, b ) => $( b ).text() < $( a ).text() ? 1 : -1 );
        const $orderedSelected = $selected.find( 'option' ).sort( ( a, b ) => $( b ).text() < $( a ).text() ? 1 : -1 );
        
        // Replace sorted options.
        $regions.append( $orderedRegions );
        $departments.append( $orderedDepartments );
        $selected.append( $orderedSelected );
        
    } )

} )( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
    
        <!-- Start : Append column --->
        <div class="col-6">
            <label class="form-label">Regions</label>
            <select name="regions" size="7" class="form-control mb-4" multiple="">
                <option value="regions-1">Region 1</option>
                <option value="regions-2">Region 2</option>
                <option value="regions-3">Region 3</option>
                <option value="regions-4">Region 4</option>
                <option value="regions-5">Region 5</option>
                <option value="regions-6">Region 6</option>
                <option value="regions-7">Region 7</option>
                <option value="regions-8">Region 8</option>
                <option value="regions-9">Region 9</option>
            </select>
            
            <label class="form-label">Departments</label>
            <select name="departments" size="7" class="form-control mb-4" multiple="">
                <option value="departments-1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="departments-2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="departments-3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="departments-4">Department 4</option>
                <option value="departments-5">Department 5</option>
                <option value="departments-6">Department 6</option>
                <option value="departments-7">Department 7</option>
                <option value="departments-8">Department 8</option>
                <option value="departments-9">Department 9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- End : Append column --->
        
        <!-- Start : Selected column --->
        <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
            <label class="form-label">Selected</label>
            <select name="selected" class="form-control mb-4 flex-grow-1" multiple="">
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- End : Selected column --->
        
    </div>  
    
    <!-- Start : Actions -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <button data-list-action="add" class="btn btn-success w-100">Add to selection</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <button data-list-action="remove" class="btn btn-danger w-100">Remove selection</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End : Actions -->
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for yout help ! It help me a lot .